# How to execute SOAP Request which contains request payload in the form of Java class

Tags: java, soap

I am automating web services APIs. I have extracted the web services from a XSD file and now they are in the form of java classes. I have constructed a request payload and assigned it to the request.

I need to execute the request which contains request payload. Is there a client available to execute this request in java???